# How to enable autocomplete in iTerm2

Tags: autocomplete, command-line-interface, iterm2

Let's say I'm in my root directory, and I have a `User` folder that I can `cd` into.  In my default Mac terminal, I can just type `cd U` + `tab`, and it autocompletes to `cd Users/`.  How do I get this to work in iTerm2?

It used to work just fine in iTerm2, but I must have changed a setting somewhere that disabled it, and I cannot figure out how to get it back.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Autocomplete in iTerm2 activates by pressing `cmd` + `;`

Comment: That works, thanks!  I was hoping I could just use `tab`.  For example, `cd vi` + `tab` would give `cd views`.  It works that way in terminal, but not in iTerm2.  I guess this is good enough for now.

Comment: That still works, this is a different autocomplete with dropdowns.

Comment: The new binding is `cmd` + `-` + `;` according to https://iterm2.com/features.html

Comment: This used to work automatically for me (automatic autocomplete) without typing cmd+;
Any ideas why it has stopped doing this? I liked it.

Comment: This does not yield the expected behavior, at least not in a latin-american keyboard layout

Answer (score 30):

Steps to add a keybinding for the TAB key:

1. <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to enter preferences
2. open tab *Keys*
3. in bottom left: add a *Key Binding* by clicking on the "+" button
4. click on area to record key
5. hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to record it

In column *Action* click on "Select Menu Item",
and then on the next dropdown select "Open Autocomplete" under the session section.

I changed it using these settings:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 22):

You can install `bash-completion` package to autocomplete by <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

- [Install `bash-completion` with `brew`](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion#homebrew)

Comment: doesn't work for me on iterm2

Answer (score 18):

In Iterm 2 , you can activate Autocomplete by pressing `command ⌘` + `;`

[image: Autocomplete]

Comment: does not work for me (iterm2 build 3.3.9, mac os 10.15.5)

Comment: Note that, on German keyboards, `;` requires you to also push the shift key.

Answer (score 12):

**Autosuggestions while you type a command in Iterm2**
(I believe this is what you where referring to)

Git Clone the zsh-autosuggestions plugin in the OhMyZsh plugin folder. (or just brew install it if on Mac)

```
$ sudo git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-~/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions
```

Once that is done, add the plugin in the ~/.zshrc file's plugin list.

```
plugins=(zsh-autosuggestions)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also enable **Auto Command Completion** (View > Auto Command Completion) which shows a window with command completion suggestions as you type. You'll have to have **shell-integration enabled** first, otherwise it will be greyed out in the menu bar.

https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for the answer when using `zsh`, add `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` to your `.zshrc` file.

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

or

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

or if you are feeling lazy

```
echo 'autoload -Uz compinit && compinit' >> ~/.zshrc && . ~/.zshrc
```